# DateTime::createFromFormat issue with particular date/time

Tags: php, datetime

I have been using the following code for a couple of months and it's been working fine, but now seems to have an issue with a certain time or time range.
I have a GPS tracker that sends it's date/time like this:
150102235335

The format is ymdhis

```
$input_array[6] = 150102235335;
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdhis', $input_array[6]);
$datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Using that time, php crashes with the following error:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object

It seems that datetime ends up empty.
However, using the time 150103004933 works just fine.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong here, or is this a bug?
Is there a better way to accomplish my date conversion?
I am using PHP 5.4.35

Comment: I insert into the database in this format for example: 2015-01-03 12:37:25

Comment: check out the answer below should be the correct format

Comment: The input is not unix timestamp. It's ymdhis (or more accurately ymdHis as pointed out by Mark below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h` is 12-hour format; and therefore 23 hours is invalid. Only values in the range 00-11 would be valid.

`H` is 24-hour format

Comment: That would explain why the other time works fine. Thank you! For the record, this is obviously the first time I was driving the car at that time of day.